# How to establish a connection between Python and IBM TM1 OLAP tool using the TM1py

Tags: cognos

Could someone please explain how to establish a connection between Python and IBM TM1 using the TM1py script.

Answer (score 1):

[TM1py](https://github.com/cubewise-code/tm1py) is a Python library that acts as a wrapper around the TM1 REST API abstracting useful operations into a Pythonic API. You might want to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

As for how to connect, there are some examples in the [tm1py-samples](https://github.com/cubewise-code/tm1py-samples/tree/master/Samples) repository which show how a connection can be made as well as other useful snippets for getting started.

From TM1py samples using standard security. You obviously want to manage your secrets in a sensible way but here is the basic idea:

```py
ADDRESS = "localhost"
PORT = 8009
USER = "admin"
PWD = "apple"
SSL = True

tm1 = TM1Service(address=ADDRESS, port=PORT, user=USER, password=PWD, ssl=SSL)
```

The instance `tm1` of the `TM1Service` object will then allow to "do" things using the REST API.

How exactly you need to connect will also be governed by the security mode being used by your TM1 server. There is an overview of the different modes [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD29G_2.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_inst.2.0.0.doc/c_integratedsecuritymode_param_n0437.html)